# Toggle Class with Jquery very fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval, fadein

Hey Guys I want to change the Color of some headlines for a short time and delayed, you can imagine it like a single running LED light every ten seconds.

```
function emphheadline() {
    $( ".menu h1" ).each(function( index ) {
            $(this).toggleClass('hover').delay(1000).next().toggleClass('hover').delay(1000    );
    });
}
```

@Raj I want to color the headlines red one after the other for a short time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(emphheadline,3000);
});
```

```js
function showandhide() {
 showmenu().delay(200).showmenu();
}

function emphheadline() {
    $( ".content h1" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover').delay(500).next().toggleClass('hover');
 });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(emphheadline,3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
}

.left .content h1 {
  -webkit-transition: color 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: color 2s;
}

.left .content h1:hover {
  color: red;
}

.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>headline 1</h1>
        <h1>headline 2</h1>
        <h1>headline 3</h1>
        <h1>headline 4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you explain it more clearly. do you want all the headlines to blink like LED on load ?

Comment: I don't think `.delay()` does what you think it does.   It pauses *animations* only, so `.next()` will occur immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a js fiddle that might work for you
https://jsfiddle.net/kht4xp1v/7/

```
function emphheadline() {

    $( ".content h1" ).each(function( index ) {

    var self = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).toggleClass('hover');
      }, index*500);

    });
}
```

you can use `setTimeout` function for the delay like shown

Comment: And do you have a clue how to get some delay between the different headlines?

Comment: i have update my answer with a new fiddle please check

Answer (score 0):

I always hate this jquery approach with dom elements. Do this:

```
(function(){
    var bulbs = [];
    $( ".menu h1" ).each(function() {
        bulbs.push({
            element: $(this),
            flag: false
        });
    };
    setInterval(function(){
        bulbs.forEach(function(bulb){
            bulb.flag = !bulb.flag;
            bulb.element.className = bulb.flag ? 'red' : 'green';
            //or bulb.toggleClass('your_cLass');
        });
    }, 100)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following example blinks ten times between red and green.

```js
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $('.menu h1').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'animation-delay': i++ + 's', 'animation-name': 'colour'})
  })
});
</script>
```

```css
.menu h1 {
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes colour {
  
  0% {
    color: red;
  }

  0.01% {
    color: green;
  }

  10% {
    color: green;
  }
  
  10.01% {
    color: red;
  }

  100% {
    color: red;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
  <h1>Heading 4</h1>
</div
```

(If you need transition instead of blinking, edit *.01% keyframe states)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/kht4xp1v/4

Here is working Javascript to accomplish this. It requires using an index that at set time intervals will loop through and create the animation:

```
function showandhide() {
    showmenu().delay(200).showmenu();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var headings = $(".content h1");
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if (index !== 0){
        headings.eq(index - 1).toggleClass("hover");
      }
      headings.eq(index).toggleClass("hover");
      ++index;
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var leds = $(".leds li").length;
var index = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {if(index == leds) { index = 0;} index = switchLed(index); }, 500);
});


function switchLed(index) {
var filter = ':nth-child(' + index + 'n)';
$(".leds li").filter(filter).removeClass("active");
$(".leds li").eq(index).addClass("active");
return ++in
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kht4xp1v/6/